# Inject attribute into child of webcomponent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, wallet-connect

I'm working on a project which uses the WalletConnect Web3 modal. The domain it's on uses `SharedArrayBuffer`, which requires COEP/COOP headers. This blocks images on 3rd party domains unless the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute is present.

This causes images in the Web3 modal to fail to load:

[image]

These images come from a webcomponent inside the main walletconnect webcomponent:

```
<w3m-wallet-image walletid="802a2041afdaf4c7e41a2903e98df333c8835897532699ad370f829390c6900f" imageid="9f259366-0bcd-4817-0af9-f78773e41900">
  <!-- shadow root -->
  <div>
    <img src="https://explorer-api.walletconnect.com/w3m/v1/getWalletImage/9f259366-0bcd-4817-0af9-f78773e41900?projectId=e903b45c47b36ce92ec3629848960470" alt="">
  </div>
</w3m-wallet-image>
```

I want to inject the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute into these image tags.

I've tried using a mutation observer to watch the DOM for changes before the modal is opened:

```
mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(addedNode) {
      console.log('added node', addedNode)
    });
  });
});

mutationObserver.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true});
```

However it doesn't seem to be called when a webcomponent is added to the DOM.